# onActivityResult in my BaseAdapter is not firing

Tags: android, baseadapter, onactivityresult

In my getView i have the following

```
holder.ivDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.ivDelete:

                        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
                        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.transaction_list_menu,
                                popup.getMenu());
                        popup.show();
                        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                    case R.id.edit:

                                        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditAmountDialogActivity.class);
                                        i.putExtra("table", table);
                                        i.putExtra("id", listItemId);
                                        ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(i, Activity.RESULT_OK);

                                        break;
                                    case R.id.delete:

                                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                                        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?")
                                                .setCancelable(false)
                                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                                                        db.deleteTransaction(table, listItemId);
                                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                    }
                                                })
                                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                        AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
                                        alert.show();

                                        break;

                                    case R.id.refresh:
                                        cursor = db.getTransactions(table);
                                        ((TransactionActivity)mContext).setBalances();
                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }

                                return true;
                            }
                        });
```

in the R.id.edit i am starting activity for result

in the EditAmountActivityDialog.class i have the following

```
dialogButtonOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                memo = etMemo.getText().toString().replace("'", "\'\'");
                timestamp = etDate.getText().toString();


                try {
                    amountDouble = Double.parseDouble(etAmount.getText().toString().replace(",", ""));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                }

                if (amountDouble == 0.0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You must enter an amount!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    hideSoftKeyboard();
                    db.updateTransaction(id, table, type, amountDouble, memo, dbTimestamp);
                    db.close();
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                    finish();
                }
```

Any idea why it is not activating the onActivityResult?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `startActivityForResult` and the `setResult` methods wrong.

You should specify a request code for your `startActivityForResult` so it can be later used in `onActivityResult` to determine which request has a result available.

Define a static and final variable on the top of your class:

```
private static final int REQ_EDIT = 100;
```

It can be anything. We are just saving it for later reference.

Then start your activity for result:

```
 case R.id.edit:
     Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditAmountDialogActivity.class);
     i.putExtra("table", table);
     i.putExtra("id", listItemId);
     startActivityForResult(i, REQ_EDIT);
     break;
```

So you now have started an activity for the result.

To finish the activity with a result use the following code:

```
...
hideSoftKeyboard();
db.updateTransaction(id, table, type, amountDouble, memo, dbTimestamp);
db.close();
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
...
```

This will return a `OK` result to your fragment.

In your fragment, override the `onActivityResult` method like below:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_EDIT:
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Do something 
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: so my onActivityResult is in my BaseAdapter class, not a fragment.

    onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("onActivityResult", "started");

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_EDIT:
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.d("onActivityResult", "notify complete");
                }
                break;
        }

    }

it will not allow me to add super.onActivityResult... but it and when i @Override it errors

Comment: I get method does not override method in its superclass

Comment: It shouldn't be. Your `onActivityResult` should be in your host `Activity` or `Fragment`, or else it won't be called. Android doesn't do black magic and find where the `onActivityResult` is hidden. It just fires the `onActivityResult` of the `Activity` or the `Fragment`. If you have overridden it, it gets executed, else it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `startActivityForResult()` with `RESULT_OK` as the `requestCode`. `RESULT_OK` value is -1 and `onActivityResult()` won't be called if the `requestCode` is below 0.

Comment: Thank you I will try changing this as soon as I can